# Android rxKotlin crash in subcribe combineLatest

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-kotlin2

I want `enable/disable` button when code & name is not empty.

**My code:**

```
btnAddItem.isEnabled = false

    val codeIsValid = RxTextView.textChanges(txvCode)
        .debounce(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map { code ->
            code.isNotEmpty()
        }

    val nameIsValid = RxTextView.textChanges(edtName)
        .debounce(350, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .map { name ->
            name.isNotEmpty()
        }

    disposableEnableButtonSave = Observables.combineLatest(codeIsValid, nameIsValid) 
        { b1, b2 -> b1 && b2 }
        .subscribe {
            if (btnAddItem.isEnabled != it){
                btnAddItem.isEnabled = it //crash here.
            }
        }
```

But it error when run:

**Logcat:**

> io.reactivex.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Animators may only be run on Looper threads
>   android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Animators may only be run on `Looper` threads

code crash is `enable/disable` button.

```
btnAddItem.isEnabled = it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (btnAddItem.isEnabled != it){
               btnAddItem.isEnabled = it
            }
        }
});
```